# Dynamically update checkbox status based on combo box selection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Suppose I have a minimal WPF application as follows:

[image]

My code consists of the following classes:

- `MainWindow`, the View which contains the following properties:

  - `List<string> Choices`
  - `string Choice`
  - `List<CheckedListItem> Checkboxes`
- `MainWindowViewModel`, the ViewModel
- `CheckedListItem`, a representation of the checkbox item, consisting of the following properties:

  - `string Name`
  - `bool IsChecked`

The XAML looks like this:

```xml
<StackPanel Width="100">
   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Choices }" SelectedItem="{Binding Choice}" ></ComboBox>
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Checkboxes}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

The following values are possible in the combo box:

- *Choice1*
- *Choice2*
- *Choice3*

I would like to save the checked box status for every selection in my combo box. So, supposing I do the following:

- Select *Choice1* in the combobox
- Check *CheckBox1* and *Checkbox2*
- Select *Choice2* in the combobox
- Deselect *CheckBox1*

If I then select *Choice1* again, I would like for my app to "remember" that *CheckBox1* was selected for *Choice1*.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Implement your logic in the setter of `Choice`?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you put the logic to change values for `Checkboxes` in the combobox's `SelectionChanged` event.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  
  
    if  Choice1 in the combobox
       Check CheckBox1 and Checkbox2
     if  Choice2 in the combobox
         Deselect CheckBox1

    // Other state logic etc as needed.
    
}
```